# Understanding subset terminology

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around subsets/element problems.

For example:

Is $\{2\} \subseteq \{2,3\}$?

I thought it was because every element in the left set is also in the set on the right.

Furthermore is

$\{2\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{1,2\})$?

I also thought this was true because the set on the left contains one or more of the elements of the set on the right.

Comment: Look at the elements of the set on the right.  $P\{(1, 2)\}$ is a set of sets, and $\{2\}$ is just a set. (Assuming you mean $P(S)$ to be the power set of $S$)

Comment: $\{2\}$ is not a subset of  $P\{(1,2)\}$ but it belongs to $P\{(1,2)\}$

Comment: @Ryan What about the first question I asked? does it make sense for 2 to be a subset of 2,3?

Comment: I also don't really understand what you mean by "set in a set". are you saying P{ } defines the set, and (1,2) is also a set that belongs to P? so (1,2) is a set within the Power Set{ } ?

Comment: @Tortar I can see how 2 would belong to {1,2} but how could It possibly belong to P{(1,2)} If that is a set in a set?

Comment: Are you sure, in the $2$nd case, that you didn' t mean to write $\mathcal P(\{1,2\})$ rather than $\mathcal P\{(1,2)\}$ ?

Comment: The first one makes perfect sense, since every element in the set on the left is also in the set on the right.  As for the second one, it comes down to what a power set is.  A power set is the set of all sub sets.  So the power set of $\{2, 3\}$ is $P(\{2, 3\})=\{ \emptyset, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{2, 3\}\}$.  So the elements of $\{2, 3\}$ are numbers, whereas the elements of $P(\{2, 3\})$ are sets.

Comment: I don’t see what the specific question really is. Your question appears to just be “Is $\{2\}\subseteq\mathcal P(\{1,2\})$?” I mean, I only see two question marks. For that reason I am choosing to downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a set. Every element that appears in $A$ is an element of $A$.

So for the first example, consider the set $A = \{2,3\}$. We see that $2 \in A$.

By definition, $S$ is a subset of $A$ ($S \subseteq A$) if and only if every element of $S$ is in $A$.

Therefore, as you said, $\{2\} \subseteq A.$

For the second example, recall the definition of **power-set.**

Let $A$ be any set. The power-set of $A$ is the set consisting of all the subsets of $A$.

Considering a set $B = \{1,2\}$, we get that

$$\mathcal{P}(B) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}.$$

We see that $\{2\} \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ but $\{2\} \not \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$. But it is true that $\{\{2\}\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, given our definition of subset [Every element in $\{\{2\}\}$ (in this case, it is only $\{2\}$) is an element of $\mathcal{P}(B)$],

Comment: Thank you for explaining this! I think that makes a lot of sense now. Is it okay if I comment on this later if I have another question regarding your explanation?

Comment: @IsabelleKreienbrink you are very welcome! I’m glad that all makes more sense now! Sure! Come back and comment here for any doubt regarding this topic :)

Answer (score 2):

$\{2\} ⊆ \{2,3\}$ because the set $\{2\}$ has elements all contained in set $\{2,3\}$.

While $\{2\} ⊆ P(\{1,2\}) = \{Ø ,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ is false because there are elements of set $\{2\}$, namely $2$, which aren't contained in $P(\{1,2\})$ : It contains just other sets, not numbers.